# How do I get RunCommandResult to determine if there was an error?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk

Is it possible to throw an exception when the shell script is executed remotely for a Azure Liunux virtual machine with the following source code and the exit code is other than `0`?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String subscriptionId="";
        AppServiceMSICredentials appServiceMsiCredentials = new 
        AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        Azure azure = Azure
                .configure()
                .withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE)
                .authenticate(appServiceMsiCredentials)
                .withSubscription(subscriptionId);
        final String rgName1 = "testlinux_group";
        final String linuxVMName = "testlinux";
        try {

            VirtualMachine virtualMachine = azure.virtualMachines().getByResourceGroup(rgName1, linuxVMName);

            System.out.println("Running Command");
            List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

            commands.add("echo 1");

            RunCommandInput runParams = new RunCommandInput()
                    .withCommandId("RunShellScript")
                    .withScript(commands);

            RunCommandResult runResult = azure.virtualMachines().runCommand(virtualMachine.resourceGroupName(), virtualMachine.name(), runParams);

            for (InstanceViewStatus res : runResult.value()) {
                context.getLogger().info("code : " + res.code());
                context.getLogger().info("status : " + res.displayStatus());
                context.getLogger().info("message : " + res.message());
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("final");
        }
```

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? Is that you want to know if the script run successfully?

Comment: As you know.
Attempting to detect an error if the result of [echo $?] Is non-zero.

Comment: As far as I knew, it will not throw an exception. It just returns error message in RunCommandResult